# How to stop function if window size is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have functions running depending on window size and changing on resize;

```
function checksize() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 1220 ) {
        //sticker1220();
    } else if ( $(window).width() > 640 & $(window).width() < 1219 )  {
        sticker950();
    } else if ( $(window).width() < 639 ) {
        sticker320();
    }
};

checksize();
$(window).resize(checksize);
```

I found out that when I open window with size eg 1230px, and then change it to 300px I have three functions working together. I solved this problem with css. But to have better code I'd like to know how to stop this functions.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting..... You want to know how to remove the code? Comment it out? Delete it? Unbind it ? Override the function?

Comment: if you have long running functions, with asynchronous callbacks or what not, I think the function pretty much has to choose to abort. i.e. in the callback, just opt not to proceed if it's no longer useful.

Comment: Here is a better way to write that program, but I'm still not sure what you want to know. What does `sticker()` do? https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/7swn68tr/

Comment: I'm guessing your sticker function should not be 3 different functions `sticker('medium')`  so that the function changes the state instead of running another function along side of it.

Comment: belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you all! @sheriffderek I tried your code, but it works the same way as mine. I need to stop function `sticker320` if window size is more than 640. here is example with my dummy functions https://jsfiddle.net/eqcxwddd/. If you look at console you will see that after resize form 320 to 640 functions `sticker320` and `sticker950` are running, if you resize after your window to 1230px, you will see that all three functions are running. But I need to stop functions which are not relevent to current window size

Comment: We asked what the sticker function does because it's important to how we would answer. You are setting event listeners with those functions, so yes - they are going to run until you remove those. You can use `.off()` But I'm guessing there is a better way to do what you want.

Comment: If you can't show us sticker() then there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: @sheriffderek here is full code, unfortunatelly I can't take html from project, as it will take too much time https://jsfiddle.net/eqcxwddd/6/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have more solution for this.
1: by using **setTimeout** and **clearTimeout**

```
var timeout = null;
function checksize() {
   if(timeout){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
   }
   timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        //Your code logic here
   }, 1000);
}

checksize();
$(window).resize(checksize);
```

2: By using javascript object

```
function windowResize(){
      var onRunning = false, self = this;
      this.onResized = function(){
            if(onRunning){
                  //Your code logic here
                  onRunning = true;
            }
            onRunning = false;
      }
}

var _myObject = new windowResize();

function checksize() {
      _myObject.onResized();
}

checksize();
$(window).resize(checksize);
```

I hope it help you more :) ...

Comment: unfortunately didn't help. here is code https://jsfiddle.net/eqcxwddd/ If you look at console you will see that after resize form 320 to 640 functions sticker320 and sticker950 are running, if you resize after your window to 1230px, you will see that all three functions are running. But I need to stop functions which are not relevent to current window size